# Does every security patch get back ported to every .NET framework?  Are there exceptions to the rule?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, .net, patching

I can imagine a scenario where Microsoft will create a security patch for some versions of .NET and not others.  This might occur in occasions it's too expensive to regression test and back port all the changes.

Are there any examples of some security fixes created for one framework and not another?

This information would be used to access risk of legacy .NET applications that [have not been migrated to the latest and most supported version of the .NET framework](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/15905/396).

Comment: If I recall correctly, yes it possible that a vendor will decide to roll out a security fix for one version and delay for an older version. I don't know if this has happened specifically for .NET framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you visit http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=pn&alpha=.net+framework you'll see Microsoft's support lifecycle for the .NET framework.

As you can see, many of the older versions are no longer supported, so Microsoft do not promise they will issue security patches for them, and you should no longer use them.